# MongoDB - Count every record where timestamp <= yesterday

Tags: php, mongodb, twitter

--SOLVED--
Timestamp within quotation marks will fix it!

I have a MongoDB instance running on my Ubuntu test bench. What I'm doing is harvesting tweets, to generate statistics about tweeting behavior in Amsterdam. One of the stats I want to visualize is the amount of tweets per day. Every tweet has its timestamp in milliseconds, so I guess I can query on that, right?

Unfortunately, the query I made doesn't generate the expected outcome:

```
db.testtweets.count({
    "timestamp_ms": {
        "$lte": 1464432361000
    }
});
```

The query above returns 0, but I expected it to return 196827 (all tweets in DB till today). What am I doing wrong? If I change the query to `IS NOT NULL` like below, it just returns the count of all the tweets like it should.

```
db.testtweets.count({
    "timestamp_ms": {
        "$ne": null
    }
});
```

Hope you guys can help me out to make a query that counts every tweet below a certain timestamp (for example yesterday: 1464354713000).

EDIT
For a full document preview, try this URL: http://pastebin.com/fddPYnX1

Comment: can you show sample documents?

Comment: or some language can make that number minus, so try with $lt: 0 to confirm

Comment: $lt0 returns zero to

Comment: Document looks like this: http://pastebin.com/fddPYnX1

Answer (score 0):

In the document, the value in seconds or milliseconds?
Usually timestamp - seconds, then you need to send the request without 000.
Try like this code:

```
db.testtweets.count({
"timestamp_ms": {
    "$lte": 1464432361
}});
```

Comment: Returns 0 as well :(